# tesseract.exe system error cannot find leptonica dll

Tags: python, anaconda, ocr, tesseract

Facing difficulties finalizing the installation of Tesseract for use from an Anaconda Jupyter notebook.

**What I have done so far**

1. In an Anaconda terminal, installed pytesseract from their [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytesseract) (`conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract`)
2. Then inside the notebook, added full path to Tesseract executable (`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\tesseract-5.3.2-hae9691c_0\Library\bin\tesseract.exe'`)

**Current issue**

```
ocr.image_to_data(image = img) # where img is a valid path to an image file
```

This line now raises two things:

- notebook error trace ends with: `CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\(...)\tesseract.exe', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 3221225781.`
- while a Windows pop-up says *tesseract.exe - system error: cannot find leptonica-1.83.1.dll*

A dll by that name is actually there: 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\leptonica-1.83.1-h7b8bf50_3\Library\bin\leptonica-1.83.1.dll'

I am aware of these two questions, which may be related but have not received an answer:

- [OCRmyPDF cannot find Leptonica Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68039321/12846804)
- [C# - Failed to find library "leptonica-1.80.0.dll" for platform x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76471150/12846804)

How do ensure that the dll is found?